# Blocking response with Jetty

Tags: java, server, jetty

I found a pretty interesting task for beginner developers with that I'm stuck.
You can post a string to some endpoint, but the server will not respond to you, it will collect all posting strings into one, and when the input string equals "done", it will respond to every connection with the result string. How can I keep the connection until the collection process is not done?

Answer (score 1):

Use Servlet API 3.0 (or newer) and it's Async processing to hold the connection.  Read up on long polling techniques.

Be aware of client and/or server idle timeout though, you can't hold the connection open indefinitely.

This task would be easier when using websocket.